# what is showsUserHeadingIndicator in react native mapbox?

Tags: react-native, mapbox, heading

How are you.
I am going to show direction of user's heading in mapbox,
In IOS version, showsUserHeadingIndicator variable exist for it,
but in React Native, there is no such variable.
so what is the alternative of this one?
Thank you.q

Answer (score 0):

showsUserHeadingIndicator is available in `react-native map-box`. You can enable the showsUserHeadingIndicator on the user location in `MGLMapView`. The indicator is so small to notice.

[image]

For more info:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/10587

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5523

Comment: Are you sure this is for react native?